# Python Audio Streaming in P2P

Tags: python, audio, streaming, p2p

I wanted to do a pet project that works sort of like Skype, sending audio between 2 computers in P2P, what module exist in python to create a project like that and how does the audio stream works in theory? how does the data transfers in live between 2 computers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python to do this, but too keep things simple I would break the problem down into smaller manageable parts.

- `audio`
  There are many python audio modules, take a look [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/) I guess you'll want one that can handle streams rather than `.mp3` or `.wav` files.
- `P2P`
  You'll need to learn up on TCP/IP - in particular `socket` can help with this ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)) but it can be quite complicated.

It sounds like a fun project, good luck!